# How to sort one array more than once in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I would know how to sort an array multiple times.
Ok it seems obvious if I explain it like that, so let me be more specific.

I have a multidimensional array:

```
$array = [
    0 => [
        'influence' => 2,
        'name' => 'abcd'
    ],
    1 => [
        'influence' => 3,
        'name' => 'cdef',
    ],
    2 => [
        'influence' => 3,
        'name' => 'bcde'
    ]
];
```

In this case, I will sort by `influence` **DESC**.
But what happened is that the element `1` of my array will be at the first place. I don't want this, so then I want to sort this sorted array by `name` **ASC** now. But whithout breaking the first sort, because if I apply this second sort my tab will be:

```
$array = [
    0 => [
        'influence' => 2,
        'name' => 'abcd'
    ],
    1 => [
        'influence' => 3,
        'name' => 'bcde',
    ],
    2 => [
        'influence' => 3,
        'name' => 'cdef'
    ]
];
```

Wherehas **I want it to be:**

```
$array = [
    0 => [
        'influence' => 3,
        'name' => 'bcde'
    ],
    1 => [
        'influence' => 3,
        'name' => 'cdef',
    ],
    2 => [
        'influence' => 2,
        'name' => 'abcd'
    ],
];
```

Anyone has an idea?

May be it's still obvious for you..
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is user defined sort function `usort`

then it would be something like

```
usort($array, function($a, $b){

    if($a['influence'] == $b['influence'])
    {
         // notice $b switched with $a to change sort direction
         return strcmp($b['name'], $a['name']);
    } else {
         return strcmp($a['influence'], $b['influence']);
    }
});
```

Code is not tested but the idea should work.

Comment: I just don't understand why do you switch `$a` and `$b` for **name** . both `influence` and `name` must be sorted ASC. so why do you switch them in another case?

Comment: He said `I will sort by influence DESC` and `I want to sort this sorted array by name ASC` that's why I wanted to show that you sort second parameter in opposite direction

Comment: oh... I see.. :-) missed that part

Answer (score 1):

If you have PHP >= 5.5.0 you can use `array_column` with `array_multisort`:

```
array_multisort(array_column($array, 'name'), SORT_DESC,
                array_column($array, 'influence'), SORT_ASC, $array);
```

Or use the [PHP Implementation of array_column()](https://github.com/ramsey/array_column/blob/master/src/array_column.php)

Comment: Thank you, but if I have a multidimensional array and I want to sort by a value from $array[0]['subarray']['type'] ?

Comment: You're welcome. That wasn't the array format from your question.  This answer addresses the array and result from your question, not any imaginable array.  Neither does the other answer.